# filebeat pod restarting multiple times and not getting logs in kibana

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

We are using ELK for logging and monitoring of my AKS Cluster. but sometimes filebeat pod is restarting and unable to pick the log into elastic search.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here the pod log as well.

> 2021-08-09T12:10:04.191Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":5128640,"time":{"ms":722}},"total":{"ticks":10563900,"time":{"ms":1266},"value":10563900},"user":{"ticks":5435260,"time":{"ms":544}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":12},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"12737862-0ffc-4805-8e49-d06e61ae95ad","uptime":{"ms":228300048}},"memstats":{"gc_next":75621616,"memory_alloc":43143552,"memory_total":11734470608},"runtime":{"goroutines":30}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":1}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":15061}},"system":{"load":{"1":2.41,"15":2.22,"5":2.36,"norm":{"1":0.6025,"15":0.555,"5":0.59}}}}}}

So, Could anybody suggest that what might be the reasons for restarting the pod multiple times and what are the ways to resolve this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ABD.png

Comment: There might be so many reasons for a pod restart. From your single log line, there is no problem associated with a pod restart. There might be more info in the whole pod log.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this would happen due to CPU and Memory limits that we set. Describe your pod to know the reason for restarts. if the reason is **OOMKilled** then check the below command to verify the current utilizations of the filebeat pod.

`kubectl top pods -n namespace`

According to the output of the top command, change(increase or describe) the CPU and Memory limits of your pod manifest.